# Unable to build project in simulator flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator

I am trying to build new project but `Podfile` always unable to created, so I do pod init to create it and when I run in simulator always getting

```
Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary /mine/Documents/trial/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not exist, cannot thin
```

I have checked flutter doctor and all of them is checked. is there a way to solve this case

Comment: Please try with flutter clean and then try again

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I have tried it multiple times, and the error still remain the same. and when I try to run from xcode, simulator always failed to build with error log that I mention in my question

Comment: what will happen if you try iOS Build from Tools>Flutter>Build iOS?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed there is no Tools menu in xcode, where I should found this Tools menu

Comment: @FaysalAhmed this question has been solved, I just build new project and restart the vs code